# ROS log file change of time-stamping format

Tags: ros, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Default format of time stamping in ROS logs are in unix time format
i.e [ INFO] [1403686233.193723830]:
i want this to be changed to ISO 8601 format
i.e 2014-06-19T19:12:32Z

i found a option to disable it using export ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT but not able to change format.

how can i do this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174892/ros-log-file-change-of-time-stamping--format/) by [AbhishekMehta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2140/abhishekmehta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2014-11-21**:
I am interested in this as well. Did you find a solution?

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2015-09-25**:
I want that, too!

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2015-09-25**:
It looks like it just uses the output stream operator of `ros::Time`: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blame/ace5b9c11af766564441bad2cb08f5fca5b73784/tools/rosconsole/src/rosconsole/rosconsole.cpp#L196-L211

**Comment by [Orchaldir](https://answers.ros.org/users/26669/orchaldir/) on 2016-04-22**:
Did you find a solution? [I am also looking for it.](http://answers.ros.org/question/232590/how-to-configure-ros_info-to-print-a-human-readable-time/)

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-04-10**:
Any update on this? I too would like this option

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2017-09-26**:
I've been looking for this too. This seems like a significant flaw in the logging system, I am going nuts looking through log files constantly translating the timestamps to find out when things really occurred.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2019-08-21**:
It would be nice if were possible to use bash to process the console string, like put a `date -d@${time}` to convert the time or `${${file}: -20}` to lop off all but the last 20 characters of the file... though maybe that would slow down console output a lot.

**Comment by [longlongago](https://answers.ros.org/users/5821/longlongago/) on 2020-12-10**:
It is fixed in the ROS Noetic: http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Change_default_time_and_walltime_format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After much digging around, I found this is possible, but the current logging architecture in ROS Kinetic makes it quite clunky. The problem is that even though ROS uses Python's logging module and provides its own user-customizable logging configuration file, the custom log stream handler defined in `rosgraph.roslogging.RosStreamHandler` completely ignores the formatting options specified in the configuration file, and hard-codes its own format. Although this is not good, it can still be overridden, but it's a bit more work.

Here's what I did to change the log's timestamp to a datetime.

1. Define your own logging configuration file by copying the default at `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosgraph/conf/python_logging.conf` and pasting it to somewhere in your project folder (preferrably a "conf" directory).

   test
2. Create a "logging.py" somewhere in your project folder (preferrably a Python package) and subclass RosStreamHandler like:

   ```
    from __future__ import absolute_import
    import os
    import time
    import logging
    import sys
    import datetime

    from rosgraph.roslogging import RosStreamHandler as _RosStreamHandler, _logging_to_rospy_names, _defaultFormatter

    class RosStreamHandler(_RosStreamHandler):

        def emit(self, record):
            level, color = _logging_to_rospy_names[record.levelname]
            record_message = _defaultFormatter.format(record)
            msg = os.environ.get('ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT', '[${severity}] [${time}]: ${message}')
               msg = msg.replace('${severity}', level)
            msg = msg.replace('${message}', str(record_message))
               msg = msg.replace('${walltime}', '%f' % time.time())
            msg = msg.replace('${thread}', str(record.thread))
               msg = msg.replace('${logger}', str(record.name))
            msg = msg.replace('${file}', str(record.pathname))
               msg = msg.replace('${line}', str(record.lineno))
            msg = msg.replace('${function}', str(record.funcName))
               try:
                   from rospy import get_name
                   node_name = get_name()
               except ImportError:
                   node_name = '<unknown_node_name>'
               msg = msg.replace('${node}', node_name)
            time_str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            msg = msg.replace('${time}', time_str)
            msg += '\n'
            if record.levelno < logging.WARNING:
                self._write(sys.stdout, msg, color)
            else:
                self._write(sys.stderr, msg, color)
   ```
3. In your custom `python_logging.conf` find the line that says:

   ```
     class=rosgraph.roslogging.RosStreamHandler
   ```

   and change it to point to your new class. If your project's Python package is called "myrobot", and you created `logging.py` directly inside that, this would look like:

   ```
    class=rosgraph.logging.RosStreamHandler
   ```
4. Now apply it. To test this, I created a simple `test_node.py` that looks like:

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import time
    import inspect
    import rospy
    rospy.init_node('test_node')
    while 1:
        rospy.loginfo("Waiting for 1 second...")
        time.sleep(1)
   ```

   and associated launch file. To use your custom logging configuration, export the `ROS_PYTHON_LOG_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable when running any node like:

   ```
    export ROS_PYTHON_LOG_CONFIG_FILE=myrobot/config/logging.conf; roslaunch myrobot test_node.launch
   ```

The output I get is:

```
[INFO] [2018-01-15 18:36:55]: Waiting for 1 second...
[INFO] [2018-01-15 18:36:56]: Waiting for 1 second...
[INFO] [2018-01-15 18:36:57]: Waiting for 1 second...
[INFO] [2018-01-15 18:36:58]: Waiting for 1 second...
```

Now clearly, this is a relatively large amount of work to change something relatively minor. Hopefully this is fixed in the next ROS release so it's a lot easier to customize.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2018-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-16**:
+1 for showing your solution, but:

> Hopefully this is fixed in the next ROS release

the chances of that happening will be infinitely larger if someone contributes the 'fix'. Perhaps that someone could be you?

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2018-01-26**:
I'll consider it. I've submitted a few pull requests before to fix bugs I've found, and they've always been ignored or rejected, which is really disheartening. I'm happy to contribute, but I also don't want to waste my time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-27**:
Working with an open-source community can be difficult, I agree. It helps if you include maintainers/reviewers in your development process though: that way you can avoid having to redo things because of design decisions that you made that the maintainer isn't comfortable merging.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-27**:
Also: changes to core components -- with a lot of history, and a large installed base -- are under extra scrutiny, as they can have a large impact if something is not up to standards. Haphazerdly introducing changes to components such as the logging systems should be avoided.

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2018-07-06**:
I assume that a similar change needs to be made for roscpp?

**Comment by [longlongago](https://answers.ros.org/users/5821/longlongago/) on 2020-12-10**:
it is fixed in ROS Noetic: http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Change_default_time_and_walltime_format

**Comment by [mpsbarra](https://answers.ros.org/users/87685/mpsbarra/) on 2021-10-20**:
One small suggestion, there is already a .isoformat() method for datetime objects.

Replacement line that is closest to OP requested format (no trailing Z): `time_str = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()`

with space (can be any single char separator) between date and time: `time_str = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(sep=' ')`

with microseconds (remove `.replace(microsecond=0)`): `time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()`